Quarkus Logging in a multi-maven-module
I have a Multi-Maven-module where some modules are quarkus-modules and others aren't.
It's clear to me that i can use io.quarkus.logging.Log in the quarkus-modules but is it possible to use quarkus Logging also in modules that are not quarkus modules?
I have tried to add the dependency quarkus-core to the non quarkus modules and then i could use the Logger. But this seems wrong to me. And how would i configure for example the log level if i do not have a application.properties?
Or do i have to use another logging framework for non quarkus modules?

I'd use SLF4J or Log4j 2 instead. Integration with Quarkus is easy, see https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-apis.

Yeah that is what I do too. But since quarkus-logging do not require the declaration of a Logger I was wondering if quarkus-logging can be used outside of quarkus modules

It probably can be, but these other modules will need a (provided or compile scoped) dependency on quarkus-core, which is almost 500KB in side, and comes with 16 compile scoped dependencies which make the footprint even larger. If you use only SLF4J then that's the only dependency, and is less than 70KB.
